# MS Dynamics AX 2009: is it possible to recreate infolog from infologdata?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

Is it possible to restore infolog from InfologData? Consider the code

```
static void Job12(Args _args)
{
    InfologData infologData;
    ;

    // here we report something
    error("something awful");
    error("something terrible");
    setprefix("scary");
    warning("mouse");

    // here we get infolog data
    infologData = infolog.infologData();

    infolog.clear(0);

    // SOME CODE

    // here we view infolog once again
}
```

what should I write instead of `// SOME CODE` to restore "something awful","something terrible", "scary\tmouse" into infolog from infologData?

My goal is to perform some operation, store infolog in database, and then show it to user, when they want it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple solution: store the returned value in a container field. Remember, do not store container fields in transaction tables, as it requires one extra disc operation per container/memo field to retrieve a record.

You may later display the value in the infolog:

```
infolog.view(x.InfoLogData);
```

You can convert the container to string:

```
info(Info::infoCon2str(x.InfoLogData));
```

Answer (score 4):

infologData can be restored in Infolog as follows:

```
    infolog.import(infologData);
```

E.g.:

```
static void Job12(Args _args)
{
    InfologData infologData;

    void saveInfolog()
    {
        ;
        // here we report something
        error("something awful");
        error("something terrible");
        setprefix("scary");
        warning("mouse");

        // here we get infolog data
        infologData = infolog.infologData();

        infolog.clear(0);
    }

    void restoreInfolog()
    {
        ;
        // here we view infolog once again
        infolog.import(infologData);
    }
    ;

    saveInfolog();
    restoreInfolog();
}
```

I separated saveInfolog from restoreInfolog to avoid issues with prefixes.

P.S. I prefer import() over view() for a simple reason: if you display an additional info/warning/error between saveInfolog() and restoreInfolog(), the output will be absolutely different - import() would be more appropriate in most scenarios.